# leads to stove element keeps burning out

Tags: stove

Why does my leads to my stove heating element keeps burning out at the terminals where they connect. I've replaced it several time, but it only last a week before the wires at the terminal burn the wires.

Comment: Make/model of stove? Picture showing the damage?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Home Improvement DIY. Could you include a picture so we better see where this is and what you mean with "burn out"? Also, please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Common causes would be too small of wire gauge or high resistance in circuit(dirty/loose connections), or using non heat rated wire(common wire instead of stove rated), if inside of stove.

Comment: It is an old HOTPOINT stove. It is the connection where the element goes into the back of the stove. Took the 2 screws loose and the terminal is still attached, but the wire isn't connected. Using the same wire, I've crimped a new terminal, but it doesn't last and you can smell burning.

Comment: A crimp is not a good connection for high current applications unless you have really good tools & technique.

Answer (score 2):

From your comment "Using the same wire, I've crimped a new terminal" it appears that the crimping or the terminal itself is not up to snuff for the job. Electric stove elements have high current and heat, which requires special engineering to handle.

You should probably get official replacement wires from the manufacturer or a certified parts source.